# Not able to read events from Azure Event Hub via App Service

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

```
Have written a service which reads events from events hub, in local system its working but when deployed as an App service to cloud not able to reads the events.
Below is the stack trace while reading events from Azure eventhub.

> 2020-04-07 09:42:59.021  INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4]
> c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler     : closeSession for
> clientName[cbs], linkName[cbs:sender], errorCondition[null],
> errorDescription[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.022  INFO 54245 ---
> [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler     :
> onLinkLocalClose clientName[cbs], linkName[cbs:receiver],
> errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.022 
> INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4]
> c.m.azure.eventhubs.impl.SessionHandler  : onSessionLocalClose
> connectionId[cbs-session], entityName[MF_7a461b_1586238177759],
> condition[Error{condition=null, description='null', info=null}]
> 2020-04-07 09:42:59.061  INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4]
> c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler     : onLinkRemoteClose
> clientName[cbs], linkName[cbs:sender], errorCondition[null],
> errorDescription[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.061  INFO 54245 ---
> [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler     :
> processOnClose clientName[cbs], linkName[cbs:sender],
> errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.061 
> INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler 
> : onLinkRemoteClose clientName[cbs], linkName[cbs:receiver],
> errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.061 
> INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler 
> : processOnClose clientName[cbs], linkName[cbs:receiver],
> errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.061 
> INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.e.impl.RequestResponseOpener   
> : requestResponseChannel.onClose complete
> clientId[MF_7a461b_1586238177759], session[cbs-session], link[cbs],
> endpoint[$cbs] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.062  INFO 54245 ---
> [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory    :
> messagingFactory[MF_7a461b_1586238177759],
> hostName[products-dev.servicebus.windows.net], info[cbsChannel closed]
> 2020-04-07 09:42:59.062  INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4]
> c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.ConnectionHandler   : onConnectionRemoteClose
> hostname[products-dev.servicebus.windows.net:5671],
> connectionId[MF_7a461b_1586238177759], errorCondition[null],
> errorDescription[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.062  WARN 54245 ---
> [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory    :
> onConnectionError messagingFactory[MF_7a461b_1586238177759],
> hostname[products-dev.servicebus.windows.net], error[null] 2020-04-07
> 09:42:59.062  INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4]
> c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.ConnectionHandler   : onTransportClosed
> hostname[products-dev.servicebus.windows.net:5671],
> connectionId[MF_7a461b_1586238177759], error[n/a] 2020-04-07
> 09:42:59.062  INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4]
> c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.CustomIOHandler     : onTransportClosed
> name[MF_7a461b_1586238177759],
> hostname[products-dev.servicebus.windows.net:5671] 2020-04-07
> 09:42:59.062  INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4]
> c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.ConnectionHandler   : onConnectionUnbound
> hostname[products-dev.servicebus.windows.net:5671],
> connectionId[MF_7a461b_1586238177759], state[CLOSED],
> remoteState[CLOSED] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.062  INFO 54245 ---
> [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.azure.eventhubs.impl.SessionHandler  :
> onSessionFinal connectionId[MF_7a461b_1586238177759],
> entityName[cbs-session], condition[null], description[null] 2020-04-07
> 09:42:59.062  INFO 54245 --- [pool-4-thread-4]
> c.m.azure.eventhubs.impl.SessionHandler  : onSessionFinal
> connectionId[MF_7a461b_1586238177759], entityName[products],
> condition[null], description[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.062  INFO 54245
> --- [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.ConnectionHandler   : onConnectionFinal hostname[products-dev.servicebus.windows.net:5671],
> connectionId[MF_7a461b_1586238177759], errorCondition[null],
> errorDescription[null] 2020-04-07 09:42:59.062  WARN 54245 ---
> [pool-4-thread-4] c.m.a.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory    :
> messagingFactory[MF_7a461b_1586238177759],
> hostName[products-dev.servicebus.windows.net], message[stopping the
> reactor because thread was interrupted or the reactor has no more
> events to process.]


Code:
```

Registering an event processor class with an instance of EventProcessorHost starts event processing. The host instance
obtains leases on some partitions of the Event Hub, possibly stealing some from other host instances, in a way that
converges on an even distribution of partitions across all host instances. For each leased partition, the host instance
creates an instance of the provided event processor class, then receives events from that partition and passes them to
the event processor instance.

There are two error notification systems in EventProcessorHost. Notification of errors tied to a particular partition,
such as a receiver failing, are delivered to the event processor instance for that partition via the onError method.
Notification of errors not tied to a particular partition, such as initialization failures, are delivered to a general
notification handler that is specified via an EventProcessorOptions object. You are not required to provide such a
notification handler, but if you don't, then you may not know that certain errors have occurred.

@RestController
public class ReceiveEventsController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceiveEventsController.class);

```
@Value("${spring.cloud.azure.eventhub.namespace}")
private String namespaceName;

@Value("${spring.cloud.azure.eventhub.name}")
private String eventHubName;

@Value("${spring.cloud.azure.eventhub.sas.key.name}")
private String sasKeyName;

@Value("${spring.cloud.azure.eventhub.sas.key.value}")
private String sasKey;

@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group}")
private String consumerGroupName;

@Value("${spring.cloud.azure.eventhub.storage.connection.string}")
private String storageConnectionString;

@Value("${spring.cloud.azure.eventhub.checkpoint-container}")
private String storageContainerName;

@Value("${spring.cloud.azure.eventhub.storage.hostname.prefix}")
private String hostNamePrefix;

@PostMapping("/receive/events")
public String postMessage() throws EventHubException, IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, URISyntaxException {

    URI uri = new URI("sb://products-dev.servicebus.windows.net");
    ConnectionStringBuilder eventHubConnectionString = new ConnectionStringBuilder()
            .setEndpoint(uri)
            .setEventHubName(eventHubName)
            .setSasKeyName(sasKeyName)
            .setSasKey(sasKey);
    EventProcessorHost host = EventProcessorHost.EventProcessorHostBuilder
            .newBuilder(EventProcessorHost.createHostName(hostNamePrefix), consumerGroupName)
            .useAzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager(storageConnectionString, storageContainerName, null)
            .useEventHubConnectionString(eventHubConnectionString.toString(), eventHubName)
            .build();

    logger.info("Registering host named " + host.getHostName()+ "Endpoint " + eventHubConnectionString.getEndpoint());
    EventProcessorOptions options = new EventProcessorOptions();
    options.setExceptionNotification(new ErrorNotificationHandler());

    host.registerEventProcessor(EventProcessor.class, options)
    .whenComplete((unused, e) ->
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            logger.info("Failure while registering: " + e.toString());
            if (e.getCause() != null)
            {
                logger.info("Inner exception: " + e.getCause().toString());
            }
        }
    })
    .thenAccept((unused) ->
    {
        logger.info("Press enter to stop.");
        try 
        {
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.info("Keyboard read failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    })
    .thenCompose((unused) ->
    {
        return host.unregisterEventProcessor();
    })
    .exceptionally((e) ->
    {
        logger.info("Failure while unregistering: " + e.toString());
        if (e.getCause() != null)
        {
            logger.info("Inner exception: " + e.getCause().toString());
        }
        return null;
    })
    .get();

    logger.info("End of PRODUCT");
    return "Event Received";
}
```

}

Comment: Hope you used same eventhub and storage account connection string from your local?

Comment: Yes, have used the same

Comment: @KuldeepSingh, can you share your code(c# or java or others)?

Comment: delete these comments and edit those into the question